# Waiting for one publish to finish before starting another

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor

I have yet to find a relatively good solution for this. Maybe the community can help?

I'm pulling data into my meteor app from some restful end points. One builds on the other. For example..I hit one end point and get a collection of authors. then I need to hit a second endpoint to pull the books each of the authors have written.

Right now I have two separate publish functions on the server side to get the sets of data, however the second one relies on the data from the first. (My initial foray in my app was simply to do it all in one publish, but this felt like not the best architecture)

Is there any way to subscribe to another publish from within another publish server side? Or, some other method of checking that i can do?
So far the internet and stack overflow have yielded little results. I am aware of the publishComposite packages available.. but they seem relatively heavy handed and don't necessarily seem applicable to what I'm trying to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i'm confused: you say you have some REST API's and publish functions? so those are distinct? if the client is hitting the REST API's to get its data, what role do the publishers have here?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
I don't own the REST API's they aren't part of my app. 
My app is consuming the data from these 2 end points. 
So to further my example,
My app calls the other parties author end point and gets a list of authors.. saves it in a collection.. and is published.. 
THen my app calls the other third party endpoint for the books for each other, and will store the books by author. 

I hope that clears up what I'm trying to do. 
I could do it all in one publish method.. but I'd like to keep the concerns seperate if possible.

Comment: ok that helps. is it your intent that the Meteor client subscribe once or twice to get all that data?

Comment: The intent is that it will subscribe to the authors publish, and subscribe to the books publish... think grid of books.. then sortable by author.. (after all the data has come down and been stored from the 3rd party end points of course) Naturally the Authors publish will need to occur first before we can use that data in the books publish.

Comment: in general, i don't like client-side joins. from your description, i would probably make 1 subscribe and combine the data. but that would probably lose reactivity of the books, so that might not be desirable. But i think the bigger architectural issue is: what drives the API calls for the authors? it feels weird if it's kicked off by a subscribe request. i think i would have something else drive it, maybe even a cron job, depending on how often i expect those lists to change on the remote service. So incoming subscribes would be served the collection data you already have, maybe updated later.

Comment: Zim, I think I'm heading down that direction. (about seperate method of getting data vs within subscribe) Not sure how I'll fully architect that but I think I have a working model of sorts to go off of. I'm hoping to find some references to the pattern we are talking about out on the web.

Comment: Why is reywood:publish-composite heavy handed? It works extremely well and is almost perfectly suited for this pattern.

Comment: Hey Michael, 
I think what I was getting at was that making the http rest calls within the composite publish was heavy.. The pattern that Zim is suggesting is a better way. 
Get the data on a timed basis etc. then publish from the data that is already in mongo at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest a divide and conquer strategy. you have basically 2 questions to answer:

1. for the collections, am i going to do a client-side or server-side join?
2. what drives calling the remote service to get the new data?

i think you can build these pieces separately and tie them together with the db and Meteor's reactivity.

e.g. you can start by writing the code that hits the remote REST APIs. i think the strategy there is to make the authors call, get the data, then make the books calls. i would do that in one function, tied together with promises. when the book data returns, write it and the authors data to their respective collections (if you don't already have that data), ensuring the foreign keys are intact. now you can tie that function to a button press, and that part is done for now.

next you can move on to the collections and publishing that data. you'll have to decide, as i mentioned, where to do that join. but do the publish(es) in such a way that, per standard Meteor practice, when the collections update in the db, your client gets the updated data.

at this point, you can test everything is storing correctly and updating reactively when you push the button.

the last piece is to decide what drives the API call, to replace the button push. as i'd mentioned in the comments, perhaps a cron job, but maybe there's something else going on in your app that makes it more natural. the danger of putting in the publish, as i think you already know, is that you could get 50 simultaneous subscribes, and you don't want to hit that REST API 50x.

Comment: Yup.. this is the pattern I'm coming to at this point. Thank you very much for your help in talking this out. :)